# Auto-generating code to create an object with an unknown class

Tags: objective-c, class, runtime, instantiation

I'm coding a script in Python that reads from a custom text and generates Objective-C code from it.  The structure of the text is as follows:

```
<XClassName> {
    property_name_1 {
        var_name_1: var_value_1
        var_name_2: var_value_2
        property_name_2 {
            var_name_3: var_value_3
        }
        property_name_2 {
            var_name_3: var_value_4
        }
    }
    property_name_3 {
    }
}
```

Resulting in Objective-C code like this:

```
XClassName* object = [[XClassName alloc] init];
object.propertyName1 = [[[object.propertyName1 class] alloc] init];
object.propertyName1.varName1 = varValue1;
object.propertyName1.varName2 = varValue2;
object.propertyName2Array = [NSMutableArray array];
{
    PropertyName2Class propertyName2 = [[PropertyName2Class alloc] init];
    propertyName2.varName3 = varValue3;
    [object.propertyName2Array addObject:propertyName2];
}
{
    PropertyName2Class propertyName2 = [[PropertyName2Class alloc] init];
    propertyName2.varName3 = varValue4;
    [object.propertyName2Array addObject:propertyName2];
}
object.propertyName3 = [[[object.propertyName3 class] alloc] init];
```

This is fine except that `PropertyName2Class` is not known during the script runtime. Right now I have to manually look for the class name for the elements expected for the object's arrays but this defeats the purpose of having a script automate it.

Is there a way to create an object dynamically without knowing its class name and assigning values to its properties?  Something like:

```
id classObject = ...; // How to instantiate a dynamic unknown class?
classObject.property1 = 1;
classObject.property2 = @"Hello World!";
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you could try using instancetype instead of id. I'm not posting it as an answer as I'm not sure if it's right but worth a look.

Comment: Is your question how to *instantiate* a class by name (but the possible classes are already defined somewhere), or how to *create* a new class at runtime?

Comment: instancetype returns the instance type of the class where it is being created (as far as I know) so it wouldn't help.

Comment: Monolo, it is not a duplicate since in this case I don't have the class name.

Comment: Is there a way you could build up the class information in memory while parsing the input file, leaving placeholders for unknown types in the output, and then do a second pass over the output? Or does the input not contain any information about these types at all?

Comment: It's really unclear at this point what you are asking. What do you mean you don't know class name, are you trying to find a class with specific properties or what? Also, see @MartinR's comment.

Comment: I agree that this is very unclear. If you're writing the script, you must also be in control of the input. What stops you from adding the class name you need to the text? «manually look for the class name for the elements expected for the object's arrays» is just unintelligible.

Comment: In the example XClassName is an already defined class.  It contains properties that are instances of other unknown objects to the script.  To clarify, the script is external and the implementation must be kept independent from any changes in the application's code (the text being parsed is generated by this).  The reason being that this output is used for other server reasons too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use the NSMutableDictionary for that:

```
NSMutableDictionary *object = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[object setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"property1"];
[object setValue:@"Hello World!" forKey:@"property2"];

NSMutableDictionary *subObject = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[subObject setValue:@"Hello sub!" forKey:@"property1"];

[object setValue:subObject forKey:@"property3"];
```

Comment: But converting this into an Application object is necessary.  I like the idea of using a dictionary instead, that way generating code like: NSDictionary* object = @{@"property1": @1, @"property2: @"Hello World!", @"property3": @[@"item1", @"item2",]} would look much cleaner.  If I can convert this dictionary later into an object would be great (which I think would be possible).

Comment: That's true, would be way cleaner this way :-) If you know all of your classes, you could just enumerate their properties using "class_copyPropertyList" and find the best match for the dictionary properties. Maybe using some kind of small helper function.

Comment: Thanks, class_copyPropertyList can give me the name of the class.  It works for me.

Answer (score 5):

If you know the class you want to instantiate exists, for example if it is passed in as a variable, then that's relatively easy. You can do:

```
- (id)createInstanceOfClass: (NSString *)className
{
  Class aClass = NSClassFromString(className);
  id instance = nil
  if(nil != aClass)
  {
    instance = [[aClass alloc] init];
  }
  return instance;
}
```

If it doesn't already exist, you can create an instance of it inside the run time, but that's a little trickier (and quite a bit dodgier too).

**Update**

I'd avoid trying to use a class with the properties that you need that already exists unless you're certain what it's implementation does. A safer solution would be to build a class up from scratch and specify what the implementation is.

Try reading:

http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-11-6-creating-classes-at-runtime-in-objective-c.html

(Not for the faint hearted!)

Also see the Objective-C runtime reference:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048

Comment: Thanks David, I don't have the name of the class name and that's the whole purpose of this question.  I do know it exists and want to create an object assuming that an object with the properties I'm assigning exists. (your link is broken by the way).

Comment: That's embarrassing! Must have gone down in the past 6 minutes. I'll go look for an equivalent (which is a shame as that link exactly went through how to create a class from scratch, complete with implementation).

Comment: Added a link to the run-time reference - unfortunately Mike Ash's guide seems to be the best I can find, so hopefully it'll become available again soon ...

Comment: Here is a [cached version of the post](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:uDd1O2gHPOkJ:www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-11-6-creating-classes-at-runtime-in-objective-c.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk), if it helps.

Comment: Just a side note: I'd avoid trying to use a class with the properties that you need unless you know what its implementation does. Just because a class conforms to the interface that you need doesn't mean that its private implementation does what you want - say you have a class with a property of a string; some implementations can have setting the value of a string kick of a sequence of events behind the scenes that you might find undesirable. A safer solution would be to build a class up from scratch if you really don't know the desired implementation.

Comment: So the code I'm generating goes in a category of an already existing class in a method that will return an instance of that class filled with the autogenerated content.  The class implementation already exists and I want to use it, I don't want to create a new class but access the already existing properties.  However the script doesn't know about this and even inside objective-c I wouldn't know the class type of the objects expected in the arrays.